# Why does Packer keep trying to remove my plugins?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I am starting my Neovim .config file from scratch and I'm having tons of problems with Packer. Now every time I call `:PackerSync` it always asks if I want to remove the directories of the plugins I have just installed.

I tried to write an auto command where packer syncs when I save my setup file but that doesn't work.

```
{
vim.cmd([[
  augroup packer_user_config
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost plugins-setup.lua source <afile> | PackerSync
  augroup end
]])
}
```

I have tried running `:PackerClean` but that just wants to remove my plugins. I don't know why but Packer has also created a directory `plugin` in my config folder with a file `packer_compiled.lua` and there are ton of random plugins in there.

I am very confused. ANY help is very much appreciated.